# Can I create fast-for-insert staging table in RedShift?

Tags: sql, bigdata, amazon-redshift

We are trying to store analytics data into RedShift on-the-fly. However single inserts work slowly with RedShift due to storage nature.

One solution is to collect these insert in our application and then to upload them into RedShift as a bulk. This will however require some nasty architectural changes in our app so I'm looking for other approaches.

For example, **is there a way to create fast staging table in RedShift** - such that it does not use compressed columnar (?) storage and allows speedy inserts, provided that we are not going to put many records into it, and it is merged into main table, say, after inserting each thousand of records?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you are barking up the wrong architectural tree.  For quick single event insert/updates you may want to consider capturing your data in Amazon [DynamoDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Introduction.html) and then pulling that data into Redshift in batch for analysis.  Here's [a link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/RedshiftforDynamoDB.html) on to how to load data from DynamoDB into Redshift.

Comment: Yes, you are right - it was the first thing I told to my architectors. However they insist that due to platform limitations I have only choise between Cassandra and Redshift. I even have no ability to aggregate my inserts locally in the file...

Comment: This [blog post](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx2ANLN1PGELDJU/Best-Practices-for-Micro-Batch-Loading-on-Amazon-Redshift) might help you at least implement micro-batching.